# Why does child directive not receive correct scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directives:

```
 function outer() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            $scope.thing = $attrs.thing;
        },
        template: '<div>Outer says {{::thing}} <div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        replace: true
    };
}

    function inner() {
        return {
        require: "^outer",
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            thing: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, outerCtrl) {
          console.log(scope); //thing is undefined here  

        },
        template: '<div>inner says {{::thing}}</div>',
        replace: true
    };
}

angular
    .module('myapp',[])
    .directive('outer', outer)
    .directive('inner', inner);
```

paired with the following html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
 <div data-outer data-thing="hi">
   <div data-inner>fff</div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that my inner directive is not receiving the thing property from the parent scope. The parent scope is correctly assigned with the 'hi' value but the child does not receive it.

https://jsfiddle.net/qbge5qse/47/

Why is this?

Comment: Did you try this. scope: {
            thing: "="
        },

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work - see https://jsfiddle.net/qbge5qse/47/

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you create isolate scope for inner directive you have 2 scope before to access outer scope.

You can access it with :

```
template: '<div>inner says {{::$parent.$parent.thing}}</div>'
```